# Filter for show and hide salary

Tags: angularjs

can you help me with this (I begin with this framework) I want to filter salary (<1000,[1000,2000],<3000) and I want to filter the type of nature (mixte,freelance,contractuel). My Program

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ePWDPdmV7gK9X7lctEX1?p=preview)

the problem the filter of freelance doesn't work and can you help me for the filter for the salary ... thank's a lot

```
 <body data-ng-controller="TestController">
        <table id="missions" border="5">
            <tr>
                <th>mission title</th>
                <th>mission salary</th>
                <th>mission domaine name</th>
                <th>mission Nature</th>
            </tr>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="mission in missions | filter:type1 | filter:type2 | filter:type3">
                <td>{{mission.title}}</td>
                <td>{{mission.salary}}</td>
                <td>{{mission.domain.name}}</td>
                <td>{{mission.missionNature.nature}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <h4>Filters</h4>
        type de contrat:<br>
        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model='type1' data-ng-true-value='contractuel' data-ng-false-value='' /> contractuel
        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model='type2' data-ng-true-value='mixte' data-ng-false-value='' /> mixte
        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model='type3' data-ng-true-value='freelance' data-ng-false-value=''/> freelance
         <br>
         salary :<br>
        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model='' data-ng-true-value='' data-ng-false-value='' /> < 1000 
        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model='' data-ng-true-value='' data-ng-false-value='' /> between 1000 and 2000
        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model='' data-ng-true-value='' data-ng-false-value='' /> between 2000 and 3000
        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model='' data-ng-true-value='' data-ng-false-value='' /> >3000
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` checks whether the given string is found in whole JSON item. You have to specify the custom attribute for which you are applying the filter.

As you have `freelance` string in every document, the filter is returning all the documents. You have to filter by specifying the field.

You should write the custom filter

```
  $scope.nature=function(item){
    if(!$scope.type1 && !$scope.type2 && !$scope.type3 ){
      return item; //if nothing is checked
    }
    else if($scope.type1===item.missionNature.nature ||$scope.type2===item.missionNature.nature ||$scope.type3===item.missionNature.nature){
      return item;
    }
  };

  $scope.salary = function(item){
    if(!$scope.salary1 && !$scope.salary2 && !$scope.salary3 &&!$scope.salary4 )
      return item; //if nothing is checked
    if($scope.salary1 && item.salary<1000)
      return item;
    if($scope.salary2 && item.salary>=1000 && item.salary<2000)
      return item;
    if($scope.salary3 && item.salary>=2000 && item.salary<3000)
      return item;
    if($scope.salary4 && item.salary>=3000)
      return item;
  }
```

Working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pFNd6Xy0tNS1fg7vYC4y?p=preview)